# Logstash - how to split array by comma?

Tags: logstash, kibana, logstash-grok

My message looks like this

```
[Metric][methodName: someName][methodParams: [ClassName{field1="val1", field2="val2", field3="val3"}, ClassName{field1="val1", field2="val2", field3="val3"}, ClassName{field1="val1", field2="val2", field3="val3"}]]
```

1. Is there a way to separate this log in more smaller ones and filter them separately?
2. If the first option isn't possible, how can I parse to get all elements of the array?

   `(?<nameOfClass>[A-Za-z]+)\{field1='%{DATA:textfield1}',\sfield2='%{DATA:textfield2}',\sfield3='%{DATA:textfield3}'\}`

Answer (score 0):

Since everything after `methodParams:` looks to be JSON you could use a JSON filter to parse it. Something like:

```
filter{
  # Parse your JSON out here using GROK to a field called myjson
  grok {
    match => {
      "message" => "methodParams: %{GREEDYDATA:myjson}"
    }
  }
  #
  json{
    source => "myjson"
  }
}
```